# Dual Boot Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I am running ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr on my laptop. I want to dual boot Windows 8.1 over it so i can boot into any of these. I have the iso file for windows 8.1.

Comment: How in this world is my query a duplicate ?

Answer (score 0):

First install windows in another partition than ubuntu.
then run the ubuntu iso cd as Test Ubuntu.
There install Boot repair. 
Instructions can be found here >> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
Hit Recommended repair.
Reboot.
If everything went well you will have grub asking to choose from ubuntu or windows!!

Comment: Why do you want him to remove Ubuntu? There is absolutely no necessity of doing it. He can still install Windows without removing Ubuntu. Stop misguiding people.

Comment: Ubuntu Won'n Be removed. He'll install win8 on another partition.this won't affect ubuntu I'm asking him to reinstall grub on the Drive so he can dual boot. I've done it with excellent results and stop degrading answers

Comment: Then be specific. Don't just say "**First install Windows**", Answers are supposed to be specific.

Comment: Happy...now or anything else

Comment: How do i install windows using iso file ?

Comment: google it. You'll find millions of links

Comment: Burn it on a dvd using brasero and install